# When you use flag(Enum) you have a limit of 64. What are the alternative when you reach the limit?

Tags: .net

With **enum** under .net the biggest number you can use is ULong.
This mean a maximum of 64 flags.

What would be the alternative when you need more than 64 flags?

**Edit**

Sorry, I forgot to add this, alternative that would still work with **bitwise operations**  at least these one; **and** and **or**.

using **Josh Einstein** suggestion, I came up with this, does it make sense?

```
class bitArrayFlag
{
    private const int flagSize = 255; //allow X numbers of flags

    public BitArray flag1;
    public BitArray flag2;
    public BitArray flagN;

    public bitArrayFlag()
    {
        int flagPos = 0;
        bool[] flagBit = new bool[flagSize];

        flagBit[flagPos] = true;
        flag1 = new BitArray(flagBit);

        flagBit[flagPos] = false;
        flagPos += 1;
        flagBit[flagPos] = true;
        flag2 = new BitArray(flagBit);

        //...
        //...
        //...

        flagBit[flagPos] = false;
        flagPos += 1;
        flagBit[flagPos] = true;
        flagN = new BitArray(flagBit);
    }
}
```

Comment: A redesign? That many flags sounds overly complex.

Comment: so far I only have 31 flags, but I just want to make sure that I have a backup plan ready if it's needed

Comment: YAGNI comes to mind. Concentrate on the problems you have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could then switch to using a [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx). You would lose all the "features" of an enum such as the default string formatting and parsing ability. A BitArray would be fundamentally similar to having a bunch of boolean fields except that the storage is much more efficient.

Indeed as Jeff says in the comments with that many independent bit states it seems like an Enum is the wrong solution anyway. A BitArray may be much more suitable for your particular scenario.

Comment: so far this seem to be the best alternative, since I cannot really group my flag

Comment: can you look at my updated question and tell me if this is what you had in mind?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You can use a single BitArray to hold as many flags as you want. var bits = new BitArray(new bool[255]); bits.Set(50, true); bits.Get(50); etc... You would probably want to define the bit positions in a traditional (non-flags) enum which can hold as many values as its underlying type. In other words bits.Set(MyFlags.Flag50, true);

Answer (score 7):

That many flags seems excessive and would suggest a redesign is needed. However, you could consider using two sets of flags. The first to designate the "flag group" and the second to designate the flags within that group. You'd have to have a class that then managed your "grouped enum" so that you could test if a flag was set or not in a simple way.

```
struct BigFlags<TGroupEnum, TFlagEnum>
{
    private Dictionary<TGroupEnum, TFlagEnum> flags;

    public BigFlags(IDictionary<TGroupEnum, TFlagEnum> flags)
    {
        this.flags = new Dictionary<TGroupEnum, TFlagEnum>(flags);
    }

    public BigFlags(TGroupEnum group, TFlagEnum flags)
    {
        this.flags = new Dictionary<TGroupEnum, TFlagEnum>() { { group, flags } };
    }

    public bool Contains(BigFlags<TGroupEnum, TFlagEnum> flags)
    {
        // TODO: Compare dictionaries and see if the passed flags are a subset of these flags.
    }

    // TODO: Equality to check exact match
    // TODO: Logical operators and operators for setting/removing flags.
}
```

Comment: sadly, I cannot really group them

Comment: @Fredou: You may be getting hung up on terminology. "Group" is just a term I used, what this really is is a way of extending the number of flags you can use. Consider "group" to be the high-order part of your flags.

Answer (score 1):

When you need more than 64 flags, you can use the 128-flags version.

```
public class BigFlags<TEnumHi, TEnumLo>
{
    private long _hi;
    private long _lo;

    public bool HasFlags(TEnumHi value)
    {
        var hiValue = (long)(object)value;

        return (_hi & hiValue) == hiValue;
    }

    public bool HasFlags(TEnumLo value)
    {
        var loValue = (long)(object)value;

        return (_lo & loValue) == loValue;
    }

    public bool HasFlags(TEnumHi hiPart, TEnumLo loPart)
    {
        return HasFlags(hiPart) && HasFlags(loPart);
    }

    public void SetFlags(TEnumHi value)
    {
        var hiValue = (long)(object)value;

        _hi = _hi | hiValue;
    }

    public void SetFlags(TEnumLo value)
    {
        var loValue = (long)(object)value;

        _lo = _lo | loValue;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var hiEnum = ((TEnumHi)(object)_hi).ToString();
        var loEnum = ((TEnumLo)(object)_lo).ToString();

        if (hiEnum.Length == 0)
        {
            return loEnum;
        }

        if (loEnum.Length == 0)
        {
            return hiEnum;
        }

        return string.Concat(hiEnum, " , ", loEnum);
    }
}
```